# How to loop over username and password from this list in Python?

Tags: python

I have a function like this:

```
import csv 

def total():
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        a = [row for row in spamreader]
        return a 
print total()
```

The output of is:

```
[['admin@gmail.com', '1234'], ['ok@gmail.com', 'metal'], ['hithere@gmail.com', 'hello']]
```

I want to loop over each username and password until the end of list. The purpose is I want to pass the username and password one by one.
First I want to use admin@gmail.com and 1234 and then proceed to another.

I tried using:

```
    def pass_username():
        with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
            spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            a = [row[0] for row in spamreader]
            return a 

def pass_password():
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        a = [row[1] for row in spamreader]
        return a
```

But this returns username at once and password at once like this:

```
admin@gmail.com
ok@gmail.com
hihere@gmail.com
1234
metal
hello
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: You already have what you need in your first function. What are you confused about  ?

Comment: See my comment in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to a single function :

```
def pass_uname_passwd :
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
                spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
                a = [(row[0], row[1]) for row in spamreader] #Make it a list of 2d tuples
                return a
```

This will return a list of 2d tuples containing username, password.

```
list = pass_uname_passwd()

for i in list :
#Use as desired, processing each (uname,passwd) at a time
```

You can simply do this from your first function as well, by using a for loop after that. The only change i suggest is using tuples instead of lists, to make the data immutable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the problem is I want username and password in different variables(which can be done too). I want to process each username and and their respective password one by one. How that can be done? Looping over takes me to the initial problem I was in.

Comment: @user1881957 How does looping over not allow you to process each uname and password one at a time ? Simple call/process what ever you want to in each run of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers cover it well. In the interests of other slightly different ways, you can also use a generator to `yield` the rows from the CSV:

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: def unames_passwd():
   ...:     with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
   ...:         reader = csv.reader(f)
   ...:         for row in reader:
   ...:             yield row
   ...:             
   ...:             

In [3]: for info in unames_passwd():
   ...:     uname, passwd = info
   ...:     print uname, passwd
   ...:     
   ...:     
admin@gmail.com 1234
ok@gmail.com metal
hithere@gmail.com hello
```

Also, in case your question is more 'How do I parse the list I get back?', you can do this:

```
In [8]: l = [['admin@gmail.com', '1234'], ['ok@gmail.com', 'metal'], ['hithere@gmail.com', 'hello']]

In [9]: for info in l:
   ...:     uname, passwrd = info
   ...:     print uname, passwrd
   ...:     
   ...:     
admin@gmail.com 1234
ok@gmail.com metal
hithere@gmail.com hello
```

Also, per your comment below, you can ignore headers by using `next()` on the `csv_file`, which will advance the iteration one step, meaning that your `for row in csv_file` loop with start on the second row of the CSV (note: `DictReader` is another option here, where each row is returned as a dictionary of `{column_header: value_at_row}`:

```
In [2]: def unames_passwd():
   ...:     with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
   ...:         reader = csv.reader(f)
   ...:         next(reader)
   ...:         for row in reader:
   ...:             yield row
```

And the output from above would be the same, minus the first row.

Comment: Will reader read the file line by line per call of the iterator of the function or will it read the complete file at the same time ?

Comment: @AshRj It will essentially act as if you are doing a normal iteration over the file (which would make more sense - I just made it a function since I thought that is what the OP wanted :) ). It will read the file in the same way `csv.reader` does, and return each row in the `for` loop. Does that make sense or did I muddle it further? :)

Comment: I thought i understood you in the first line. Then the second line came .. :)  In simple words, in one function call, will a single line be read from the file or will multiple lines be read ? `csv.reader` creates an iterable, but does that work in this case, because of the `yield`  statement. Logically, it should (according to me). I just wanted to verify whether i am thinking correctly.

Comment: @AshRj Ah, gotcha - yes :) It will still behave in the same way - only difference is that each row is yielded to the `for` loop that is calling it. However the reading still reads the same way as 'usual'.

Comment: Thanks @RocketDonkey for the explanation. I was wondering if I could remove the first line i.e admin@gmail.com 1234 as I put heading in ther.

Comment: @user1881957 No problem, and sure thing :) One trick you can do is use the `next()` function. I'll drop in an edit, but what it does is 'advances' an iterator to the next item. So if we were to say `next(csv_file)` just before we started the `for row in csv_file` portion, we would actually be starting at the second line of the file since we 'advanced' past the first one. Does that make sense?

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thanks so much! Really Appreciate it.

Comment: @user1881957 No problem at all, and good luck with everything!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

```
def total(f):
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile: 
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
        a = [f(row) for row in spamreader]
        return a 
def func(username, password):
    print username, password
print total(func)
```

Or a more straightforward way:

```
def total():
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile: 
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
        for username, password in spamreader:
            print username, password
        return a 
print total()
```